# Tkinter - Notebook, set a particular tab in front at instantiation

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

A button '+' adds a tab to my notebook. However, I'd like the latest tab created to be automatically selected/displayed, so the user doesn't have to click on it.

I assume it must be done at the creation of the tab (in AddTab, see a simplified version of my code below) but I can't find a method or an option for that.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class MyFrame(Frame):
    def AddTab(self):
        tab=ttk.Frame(self.NB)
        self.NB.add(tab, text="Tab")
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("Title")
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(column= 0, row=0, sticky=N+W+S+E)

        self.Frame_buttons=ttk.Frame(master)
        self.Frame_buttons.grid(column=0, row=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=(N,W,S,E))

        self.NB=ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.NB.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=1, sticky=(N,W,S,E))

        self.add_tab=ttk.Button(self.Frame_buttons, text="+", command=self.AddTab)
        self.add_tab.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(N,W,S,E))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to add `self.NB.select(tab)` in `AddTab()`